# Настройки .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуете.

Мне необходимо написать что-то в .htaccess таким образом, чтобы все запросы он перенаправлял в index.php, но при этом выдавал остальные файлы (стили, скрипты картинки).

Сейчас в нем у меня вот что:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Я нашёл, что

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

все существующие папки не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

все существующие файлы не будут обрабатываться регулярным выражением.

Но что-то всё равно не понимаю, как это использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, собственно, у вас и есть готовый htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Последняя строчка говорит, что запрос вида `server/some/attr?a=b` будет преобразован в `index.php?route=some/attr&a=b`.

Comment: Не могли бы вы ещё пояснить, возможно ли не выбирать только файлы с разрешением .php и .tpl, то есть запрос вида "http://site/manager/primer.php"  будет перенаправлен, а "http://site/manager/primer.css" отдаст файл

Comment: еще раз:

если "manager/primer.php" - существует - он будет показан, если нет - то эта строка как параметр будет передана в index.php.

Comment: Вы не поняли, если разрешение запрашиваемого файла ".php", то эта строка как параметр будет передана в index.php, и неважно, существует этот файли или нет, но файлы с другим расширением нужно показывать.